# How to confirm a JavaScript popup using Nokgiri or Mechanize

Tags: ruby, xss, nokogiri, mechanize, ruby-2.3

I'm running a script that will open up on my localhost. My local server is a vulnerable web app test suite.

I'm trying to confirm a XSS popup from a JavaScript alert. For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:65412/v?=0.2<script>alert("TEST");</script>
```

I need to confirm the popup happened using either Mechanize or Nokogiri. Is it possible to confirm that the popup is there with Nokogiri or Mechanize?

For example:

```
def page(site)
  Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get(site))
end

puts page('http://127.0.0.1:65412/v?=0.2<script>alert("TEST");</script>')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri, and Mechanize because it is built on top of Nokogiri, can parse the HTML and return the `<script>` tag's contents. The tag's content is text so at that point it's necessary to look inside the text to find what you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<head>
<script>alert("TEST");</script>
</head>
</html>
EOT

script_content = doc.at('script').content # => "alert(\"TEST\");"
```

It's easy to check to see if a sub-string exists at that point:

```
script_content['alert("TEST");'] # => "alert(\"TEST\");"
```

or:

```
!!script_content['alert("TEST");'] # => true
```

Note: It's not possible with Nokogiri, or Mechanize, to tell if a pop-up occurred as that'd happen inside a browser as it runs the JavaScript. Neither Nokogiri or Mechanize understand or interpret JavaScript. Only a tool like Watir or that interprets JavaScript could do that.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not, and that's because neither Mechanize or Nokogiri run Javascript.

Instead, you could use [Selenium](http://seleniumtutorials.com/2013/09/25/selenium/ruby-selenium-webdriver-tutorial-part-1-writing-our-first-test/).

Something like this:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class AlertChecker
  Driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  def initialize(url)
    Driver.navigate.to url
  end
  def raise_alert(text)
    Driver.execute_script "alert('#{text}')"
    self
  end
  def safely_get_alert
    begin
      Driver.switch_to.alert
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoAlertOpenError
    end
  end 
end
```

Usage:

```
alert_checker = AlertChecker.new("http://my.website")

alert = alert_checker.safely_get_alert
# => nil

alert_checker.raise_alert("hack")
alert = alert_checker.safely_get_alert
puts alert.text
# => 'hack'

# As far as I'm aware Selenium doesn't have a built-in way
# to tell you if it's an alert, confirm, or prompt.
# But you know it's a prompt, for example, you could also send
# keys before accepting or dismissing
alert.accept

alert = alert_checker.safely_get_alert
# => nil
```

There are some tricky things with Selenium's handling of alerts, though.

There's no way for your code to detect the type (prompt, confirm, or alert) without using something like `rescue` or `try`. Everything is reached through `switch_to.alert`.

Also, if your browser has an alert open you cannot run any subsequent commands unless you handle alert. Say you try and `navigate.to` while the alert is open; you'd get an error along the lines of *You didn't handle the alert* and your `navigate.to` command would have to be rerun. When this error is raised, the alert object will be lost as well.

It's a little unappealing to use rescue as a control structure in this way but I'm not aware of any other option

Comment: Well what about this, would there be a way to find it through the html? Like would there be a script tag to parse?

Comment: Probably the easiest way for sure to know the XSS occurs is to run the Javascript (cannot do with with Nokogiri / Mechanize).

Comment: Yeah I didn't think this was going to be easy

Comment: What do you mean to run the javascript?

Comment: Mechanize/Nokogiri just get the HTML. It includes Javascript, but that's never actually run. Like if you have a website that loads all its content through AJAX then you'd never see it. Selenium on the other hand uses an actual browser, so it can run the Javascript.

Comment: Really I just need to verify that the tag is there, if the tag is there then Nokogiri should be able to pick it up correct?

Comment: @papasmurf in that case maybe something as simple as `\`curl <url>\`.include? %{alert("TEST")}` would suffice